# Even root cannot change the ownership of a file in external drive?

Tags: centos7, chown

Got the below error from qemu:
`Unable to complete install: 'Cannot access storage file '/run/media/msingh/WDELEMENTS1/test/CentOsRestoreTest.qcow2' (as uid:107, gid:107): Permission denied'`

So tried to change the ownership as root but it still fails:

```
[root@centos ~]# chown qemu.qemu /run/media/msingh/WDELEMENTS1/test/CentOsRestoreTest.qcow2
chown: changing ownership of ‘/run/media/msingh/WDELEMENTS1/test/CentOsRestoreTest.qcow2’: Operation not permitted
```

Info about the path/drive:

```
[root@centos ~]# df -hT /dev/sda1
Filesystem     Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      vfat  2.8T   55G  2.7T   2% /run/media/msingh/WDELEMENTS1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VFAT filesystems do not support the notion of file ownership.  Instead, when the filesystem is mounted, the mount command sets a uid/gid which are considered to own everything in that filesystem.

Thus, to change the ownership of a VFAT filesystem's contents, you need to unmount the filesystem and remount it with the desired uid/gid.